# Inserting into a database table not working with Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, postgresql

I am inserting into a table using the following code:

```
## Connection established ##

sql = """ INSERT INTO Singer ( name ) VALUES( %s ) """

params = ('Rihanna',)

cursor.execute(sql, params)

cursor.fetchall()  ## Result - into no result set 
cursor.description ## Result - Nonetype
```

I am not able to understand where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to commit your change.

```py
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """ INSERT INTO Singer ( name ) VALUES( %s ) """

params = ('Rihanna',)

cursor.execute(sql, params)
conn.commit() # Important, apply changes to database!
cursor.fetchall()  ## Result - into no result set 
cursor.description ## Result - Nonetype
```